# Web Api incorrectly deserializing a list of enums

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

So, I'm using a web API controller to accept JSON requests. It is mapping to a model object that includes a list of enums. The problem I am having is that if the JSON includes an invalid value, it does not seem to be deserializing correctly. I would expect an invalid value to be mapped to the 0 value type in my enum list, however that is not happening.

There are 3 primary cases that I've isolated: If the JSON is in the form of

```
    ...
    "MyEnumList":["IncorrectEnum", "One", "Two"]
    ...
```

The value is not mapped at all, and I simply get a list with the two valid values. However, if I supply this JSON:

```
   ...
   "MyEnumList":["123", "One", "Two"]
   ...
```

I get a list with 3 objects, where the first object is of type "MyEnum" and has the value 123, even though that is not defined in my enum. The same happens if I supply this JSON syntax:

```
   ...
   "MyEnumList":[123, "One", "Two"]
   ...
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here, and how I can ensure that the values are always mapped to a valid type?

For reference, The model object, which contains a list of my enum:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
       public List<myEnum> MyEnumList { get; set; }
    }
```

and the simple enum:

```
    public enum myEnum 
    {
       Zero = 0,
       One = 1,
       Two = 2
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that `123` can get assigned to an enum that does not contain a value for `123` is not entirely the fault of Json.Net.  It turns out that the C# runtime itself allows this assignment.  You can see this for yourself if you run this small demonstration program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Direct cast from integer -- no error here
        MyEnum x = (MyEnum)123;
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        // Parsing a numeric string -- no error here either
        MyEnum y = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "456");
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Zero = 0,
        One = 1,
        Two = 2
    }
}
```

So what is likely going on is that Json.Net is simply using `Enum.Parse` behind the scenes.  I do not know why you are not getting an exception on your first case, however.  When I try that, it fails (as I would expect).

In any case, if you require strict validation of possibly bad enum values, you can create a custom `JsonConverter` that will force the value to be valid (or optionally throw an exception).  Here is a converter that should work for any kind of enum.  (The code could probably be improved upon, but it works.)

```
class StrictEnumConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType.BaseType == typeof(Enum));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

        try
        {
            // We're only interested in integers or strings;
            // all other token types should fall through
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Integer ||
                token.Type == JTokenType.String)
            {
                // Get the string representation of the token
                // and check if it is numeric
                string s = token.ToString();
                int i;
                if (int.TryParse(s, out i))
                {
                    // If the token is numeric, try to find a matching
                    // name from the enum. If it works, convert it into
                    // the actual enum value; otherwise punt.
                    string name = Enum.GetName(objectType, i);
                    if (name != null)
                        return Enum.Parse(objectType, name);
                }
                else
                {
                    // We've got a non-numeric value, so try to parse it
                    // as is (case insensitive). If this doesn't work,
                    // it will throw an ArgumentException.
                    return Enum.Parse(objectType, s, true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            // Eat the exception and fall through
        }

        // We got a bad value, so return the first value from the enum as
        // a default. Alternatively, you could throw an exception here to
        // halt the deserialization.
        IEnumerator en = Enum.GetValues(objectType).GetEnumerator();
        en.MoveNext();
        return en.Current;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is a demo using the converter on a hodgepodge of values:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The first 12 values should deserialize to correct values;
        // the last 7 should all be forced to MyEnum.Zero.
        string json = @"
        {
            ""MyEnumList"":
            [
                ""Zero"", 
                ""One"", 
                ""Two"", 
                0,
                1,
                2,
                ""zero"",
                ""one"",
                ""two"",
                ""0"",
                ""1"",
                ""2"",
                ""BAD"", 
                ""123"", 
                123, 
                1.0,
                null,
                false,
                true
            ]
        }";

        MyClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json, 
                                                   new StrictEnumConverter());
        foreach (MyEnum e in obj.MyEnumList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Zero = 0,
        One = 1,
        Two = 2
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public List<MyEnum> MyEnumList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Zero
One
Two
Zero
One
Two
Zero
One
Two
Zero
One
Two
Zero
Zero
Zero
Zero
Zero
Zero
Zero
```

By the way, to use this converter with Web API, you'll need to add this code to your `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters 
                                  .JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
settings.Converters.Add(new StrictEnumConverter());
```

Comment: Testing this, if I send:
        ...
        "MyEnumList":["123", "One"]
        ...
I get the same results as before, which is an enum value that is equal to 123. It is not mapping to a valid enum value.

Comment: Did you add the converter to the global configuration as shown above?

Comment: Yes, although I believe I found the problem. I was decorating the list with [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))], which seemed to be what was causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, that would explain it.

Comment: Then, an additional question: is there a way to have the enum serialized to its string value rather than its numeric value, without breaking this?

Comment: Yes, you can implement the `WriteJson` method (and remove the `CanWrite` override).  I'll update my answer.

Comment: OK, I've updated the converter.  Should work the way you want now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45927/discussion-between-joshua-dixon-and-brian-rogers)