# Invalid Enum value in web api request not throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a post method that takes a request object, inside that request object i have an enum.

```
 public class SearchRequest
    {
        [Required]
        public EnumType EnumType { get; set; }
    }
```

where EnumType is

```
 public enum EnumType
    {
        First,
        Second,
        Third
    }
```

I am firing a request with some junk in for enumType like so

```
{
 "enumType": "BLAHBLAHBLAH",  
}
```

I am expecting a nice error message but instead in the deserialisation phase it is just converting it to 'First', how can i change this behaviour.

Comment: You can work around it using `EnumType { None = 0, ... }`.

Comment: I want it to throw an error though during deserialisation

Comment: Then apply the custom serializer demonstrated in the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296149/web-api-incorrectly-deserializing-a-list-of-enums). Feel free to @notify me if you encounter any specific issue implementing it, I'll reopen your question if you inclide additional details.